# For command + interpolation: need some tips

Tags: matlab, datetime, loops, interpolation

I have a matrix `A` with three columns: daily dates, prices, and hours - all same size vector - there are multiple prices associated to hours in a day.

sample data below:

```
A_dates =          A_hours=        A_prices=
[20080902         [9.698           [24.09
20080902          9.891             24.59
200080902         10.251            24.60 
20080903          9.584             25.63
200080903         10.45             24.96
200080903         12.12             24.78
200080904          12.95            26.98 
20080904           13.569           26.78
20080904]          14.589]          25.41]
```

- Keep in my mind that I have about two years of daily data with about 10 000 prices per day that covers almost every minutes in a day from 9:30am to 16:00pm. Actually my initial dataset time was in milliseconds. I then converted my milliseconds in hours. I have some hours like 14.589 repeated three  times with 3 different prices. Hence I did the following:

  time=[A_dates,A_hours,A_prices]; 
  [timeinhr,price]=consolidator(time,A_prices,'mean'); where timeinhr is both vector A_dates and A_hours

to take an average price at each say 14.589hours.
then for any missing hours with .25 .50 .75 and integer hours - I wish to interpolate.

For each date, hours repeat and I need to interpolate linearly prices that I don't have for some "wanted" hours. But of course I can't use the command interp1 if my hours repeats in my column because I have multiple days. So say:

```
%# here I want hours in 0.25unit increments (like 9.5hrs)
new_timeinhr = 0:0.25:max(A_hours));

day_hour = rem(new_timeinhour, 24);

%# Here I want only prices between 9.5hours and 16hours
new_timeinhr( day_hour <= 9.2 | day_hour >= 16.1 ) = [];
```

I then create a unique vectors of day and want to use a for and if command to interpolate `daily` and then stack my new prices in a vector one after the other:

```
days = unique(A_dates);
for j = 1:length(days);
    if A_dates == days(j)
       int_prices(j) = interp1(A_hours, A_prices, new_timeinhr);
    end;
end;
```

My error is:

> `In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.`

How can I write the `int_prices(j)` to the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend converting your input to a single monotonic time value.  Use the MATLAB `datenum` format, which represents one day as 1.  There are plenty of advantages to this: You get the builtin MATLAB time/date functions, you get plot labels formatted nicely as date/time via `datetick`, and interpolation just works.  Without test data, I can't test this code, but here's the general idea.

Based on your new information that dates are stored as 20080902 (I assume yyyymmdd), I've updated the initial conversion code.  Also, since the layout of A is causing confusion, I'm going to refer to the columns of A as the vectors `A_prices`, `A_hours`, and `A_dates`.

```
% This datenum vector matches A.  I'm assuming they're already sorted by date and time
At = datenum(num2str(A_dates), 'yyyymmdd') + datenum(0, 0, 0, A_hours, 0, 0);
incr = datenum(0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0);  % 0.25 hour
t = (At(1):incr:At(end)).';       % Full timespan of dataset, in 0.25 hour increments

frac_hours = 24*(t - floor(t));        % Fractional hours into the day
t_business_day = t((frac_hours > 9.4) & (frac_hours < 16.1));  % Time vector only where you want it

P = interp1(At, A_prices, t_business_day);
```

I repeat, since there's no test data, I can't test the code.  I highly recommend testing the date conversion code by using `datestr` to convert *back* from the datenum to readable dates.

Comment: My date format looks like 20080902 20080903 ... but in
P = interp1(A(:,2), At, t_business_day); I have to include my vector of prices that I wish to interpolate.

Comment: I'm just going off your spec.  You say A is dates, prices, hours, so that's what I wrote, assuming A(:,2) were the prices.  I'll edit my answer to just name the vectors instead.

Comment: I just fixed a typo in interp1, as well.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I will try your code later and get back to you! thanks again

Comment: if you look at my code above (I have yet tried yours yet - but if it works I will implement yours since it is most efficient) why do you think I can end up with some elements in P with values NaN? I got like 10 NaN in roughly 5000 elements in P. Anyhow, I am sure I can avoid this problem with your code once I try it out later.

Comment: If none of your inputs are NaN, then NaN can only happen if you ask interp1 to extrapolate.  That is, if the `XI` input has values outside the range of `X`.  In your case, that probably means at least one day doesn't have price data covering the full 9.4 to 16.1 span, plus a little extra for rounding.

Comment: ah I see! can this also occur under your code? Sorry for all those questions... :)

Comment: Less likely, since there are only two endpoints.  The question is, does this show a flaw in your data that will be papered over by interpolating?  You're the only one that can answer that...

Comment: @Peter I am trying your code but I for the datenum(sprintf... I can't apply it on a vector. I need to first go through a funarray no?

Comment: Good point, I'm making one more edit to change out the sprintf for num2str, which will work on a vector.  If you want any more code fine-tuning, please edit your post to include some sample data that can be used to test.

Comment: @Peter I added a sample data above in my original post. I ran your code but no success. First there was a typo in the first line in terms of the brackets: it should be: `At = datenum(num2str(A(:,1)), 'yyyymmdd') + datenum(0, 0, 0, A(:,2), 0, 0);` and then my final value for P is P=[] ... thanks for help

Comment: OK, I'll fix that typo, plus one more... frac_hours is actually fraction of a day, so I had to scale it up by 24.  Now P produces values.

Answer (score 1):

Converting days/hours to serial date numbers, as suggested by [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933283/97160), is definitely the way to go. Based on his code (which I already upvoted), I present below a simple example.

First I start by creating some fake data resembling what you described (with some missing parts as well):

```
%# three days in increments of 1 hour
dt = datenum(num2str((0:23)','2012-06-01 %02d:00'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');   %#'
dt = [dt; dt+1; dt+2];

%# price data corresponding to each hour
p = cumsum(rand(size(dt))-0.5);

%# show plot
plot(dt, p, '.-'), datetick('x')
grid on, xlabel('Date/Time'), ylabel('Prices')

%# lets remove some rows as missing
idx = ( rand(size(dt)) < 0.1 );
hold on, plot(dt(idx), p(idx), 'ro'), hold off
legend({'prices','missing'})
dt(idx) = [];
p(idx) = [];

%# matrix same as yours: days,prices,hours
ymd = str2double( cellstr(datestr(dt,'yyyymmdd')) );
hr = str2double( cellstr(datestr(dt,'HH')) );
A = [ymd p hr];

%# let clear all variables except the data matrix A
clearvars -except A
```

Next we interpolate the price data across the entire range in 15 minutes increments:

```
%# convert days/hours to serial date number
dt = datenum(num2str(A(:,[1 3]),'%d %d'), 'yyyymmdd HH');

%# create a vector of 15 min increments
t_15min = (0:0.25:(24-0.25))';                  %#'
tt = datenum(0,0,0, t_15min,0,0);

%# offset serial date across all days
ymd = datenum(num2str(unique(A(:,1))), 'yyyymmdd');
tt = bsxfun(@plus, ymd', tt);                   %#'
tt = tt(:);

%# interpolate data at new datetimes
pp = interp1(dt, A(:,2), tt);

%# extract desired period of time from each day
idx = (9.5 <= t_15min & t_15min <= 16);
idx2 = bsxfun(@plus, find(idx), (0:numel(ymd)-1)*numel(t_15min));
P = pp(idx2(:));

%# plot interpolated data, and show extracted periods
figure, plot(tt, pp, '.-'), datetick('x'), hold on
plot([tt(idx2);nan(1,numel(ymd))], [pp(idx2);nan(1,numel(ymd))], 'r.-')
hold off, grid on, xlabel('Date/Time'), ylabel('Prices')
legend({'interpolated prices','period of 9:30 - 16:00'})
```

and here are the two plots showing the original and interpolated data:

[image: original_data]
[image: interpolated_data]

Comment: PS: I started writing my answer before seeing your recent edit (with the newly posted sample data)... Still my example can be adapted to your data

Comment: wow great example! Amro and Peter I'll get back to you once I try (now) the updated version of the code on my high-frequency trading data. Thanks guys!

Comment: I just ran again Peter's code and works superb but I will take a closer look to your setup also because I would like to graph and see where I interpolated the data. I have to interpolate per hours, and now minutes, and then seconds!!! Thanks!

Comment: Amro and @Peter the more I go through your codes the more I like it! It simplifies a lot of my work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved it this way:

```
new_timeinhr = 0:0.25:max(A(:,2));
day_hour = rem(new_timeinhr, 24);
new_timeinhr( day_hour <= 9.4 | day_hour >= 16.1 ) = [];

days=unique(data(:,1));
P=[];
for j=1:length(days);
    condition=A(:,1)==days(j);
    intprices = interp1(A(condition,2), A(condition,3), new_timeinhr);
    P=vertcat(P,intprices');
end;
```

Comment: you could also store the result in a cell array (`P`), then concatenate into a matrix once done